# Network operations and parsing on separate threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is there a benefit to be gained by splitting the network operation and parsing onto separate threads? I realize that both should be executed on non-UI threads; that's not my question. Should the networking operation run on a network thread and then pass the data off to the parsing thread to be parsed?

Here are some tradeoffs that I see:

**pro**

- The two types of operations can't block each other (?)
- The two types of operations can be put in separate thread pools and tuned separately

**con**

- Context switch can introduce some delay
- More threads, more complex
- Stream parsing becomes difficult/impossible

Comment: i think, that you can use parsing thread only if you need to download "next" data at the same time as you are parsing "prev" data ... in other cases like parsing after/at the same time(stream parsers) as downloading network thread should be enough

Comment: imo that depends on the impact of the data to be parsed. In my experience the impact of parsing a complex json is insignificant if compared with the time need to download the data

Comment: @Selvin Good point, I've added the con that stream parsing is difficult/impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nearly answered the question yourself.  There really won't be, unless the parsing you are performing will take a long time.  Network operations are almost always going to be the bottleneck in your application, so consider the tradeoff of whether the processing you are performing could cut into valuable time that the thread could instead be downloading from the internet.

For the vast amount of applications where the parsing takes microseconds to milliseconds I don't see much noticeable difference to the user.  If your parsing will take considerable time you could create a separate thread for parsing, like you said, and create a producer/consumer relationship between them.  This will add quite a bit of complexity to your application where I don't think it's worth it unless you have performed some sort of profiling to determine this is a problem.

Make sure you are not making premature optimizations to your application and that you have profiled it (or know for sure) to determine whether this is necessary. :)

Comment: Thanks, that's about where my thoughts were. I just needed some confirmation.